# Domain name not pointing on root directory

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, dns, laravel-8

I am using amazon linux ec2 instance i.e working fine with IP address.

My apache root directory is

> /var/www/html

that is working fine when I am accessing my instance IP address.

Issue is when I am using my domain name. It's working only when I am adding "html" after domain name, like

> domain/html

I implemented SSL certificate using let's encrypt library, may be that is reason of this issue

I tried to change my httpd.conf directory URL with www directory but that's not working.

Domain name continuously showing below error message but working when I am adding "html" at the end of domain name

> Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access this resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like issue is with your vhost config, as you mentioned SSL certificates generated using Let's encrypt, check host file on below path and change document root directory with your original directory. Also check is there any other host file as well or not.

> /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf